# prettier rule best practice

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I have the following code:

```
const [transactions, updateTransactions] = React.useState<
    CustomTransaction[]
  >([...transactionList]);
```

This code was formatted using prettier.

How can this be a good idea to format code like this ? It just doesn't make sense to me. Is there any rule that disables such kind of formatting or how do you handle situations like this ?

**UPDATE:**

```
 "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
 "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
 "prettier": "^2.2.1"
 "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
 "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
 "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
 "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
 "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
```

I am also using the latest typescript.

Comment: Generally JavaScript formatters will struggle with TypeScript, since it contains syntax they don't recognise. This looks like one of those cases.

Comment: Which version are you using? The latest breaks argument to fit the print width.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I updated the question and included the versions.

Comment: @DBS what's the workaround ?